# Accessing array keys with PHP loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm good with PHP, but my brain is slow working with arrays.

This is an API, returning a JSON I already encoded into an array.

http://data.gate.io/api2/1/tickers

Let's call it $myarray

```
$index=1;
foreach($myarray as $key => $value)
    {
    echo $index." ".$value['last']."<BR>";
    $index++;
    }
```

Everything works ok, I can access all the fields inside the sub-arrays; but I can not access the "name" of the subarray ("btc_usdt" for example).
If I use $value[0], I got a null.
If I use $value alone, I got the string "array".
Is there any way I can access that info?

Comment: are you trying to display name instead of index? added name to my answer

Comment: If $value is another array, he wants to get the key names of elements inside $value (need a nested foreach possibly). As $key will ***not*** have the name, as that only contains the name of that parent $value array.

Comment: @IncredibleHat the name is the `$key` as the json array is an array of arrays. my answer is a working example getting the name and value "last"

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is working, I assume you converted it with `json_decode(..., true);`. Then the answer is really simple. The name of the current sub-array is stored in the `$key` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The "name" is stored in $key. Here is a working example ...

```
<?php
$myarray = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://data.gate.io/api2/1/tickers'), true);

$index = 1;
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo $index . " " . $key . " " . $value['last'] . "<BR>";
    $index++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because each sub-arrays are `stdClass objects`, you can do it like this

```
$index=1;
foreach($myarray as $key => $value) {
    echo $index . " ". $value->last . "<BR>";
$index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and working for the link you provided. I think you are not formatting the JSON data correctly.

```
$data = file_get_contents( 'http://data.gate.io/api2/1/tickers' );
$formattedData = json_decode( $data, true );
$index = 1;
foreach($formattedData as $key => $value)
{
    echo $index . " name: {$key}, last: " . $value['last'] . "<BR>";
    $index++;
}
```

The name of the array is the key of the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still confused with the above working example then I have another solution here:

```
$myarray = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://data.gate.io/api2/1/tickers'), true);
$index = 0;
$newarray = [];
foreach ($myarray as $key => $value) {
$newarray[$index] = $value;
$newarray[$index]['name'] = $key;
$index++;
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($newarray);exit;
```

Now the name attribute is shifted to the sub-array and you can easily iterate newly generated array i.e. $newarray.

Hope it helps!